# Onion(not peel) water for fertilizer?

Tags: tree-care, fertilizer, onions

I have heard several times that onion peel water is very good for fertilizer, but I never heard about onion itself. Is it good or bad for plants?

I only heard if it can be used for insecticide, but I used it without any mix anything but the ants and some insects still exist on my mango, cherry, longan, and matoa tree.

Comment: Onion or garlic *may* temporarily affect some things that eat leaves and don't like the taste. Not aware of either one killing any insect, so I suspect that's bad information. They do have some anti-fungal properties. Then again, not all insects are bad for plants, so due consideration of the negative and positive impact of things that *do* kill insects is advisable before use.